# Rectangular bounding box curved in D3.js

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, extents, d3

I am trying to project polygons to a map with a static background image using D3.js. The polygons looked slightly off in relation to the background so I drew the bounding box of the image, and sure enough, it's not matching.

I've uploaded the code as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/vienno/5b629f7f9397baab8d65) and the result is [live here](http://bl.ocks.org/vienno/fce450596f3ad558e4f7). As you can see, the bounding box does not have the same proportions as the background, and also it's curved even though the geojson file clearly contains a rectangle.

[image: Example of curved bounding box]

In order to get the background image and the bounding box I took the following steps:

1. Downloaded raster data from Natural Earth.
2. Cropped the raster image in QGIS using `Raster->Extraction->Clipper`.
3. Saved the bounding box of the cropped image with `gdaltindex bounds.shp cropped.tif`, and converted the shapefile to GeoJSON in QGIS.
4. Used the technique described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object) to scale the projection to the bounding box.